# Grails unique domain constraint

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am new to grails and I have came across this problem. In my form there are Name and Code. The code have to be unique so if the user try to register with the same code that already exist it will show the user and error message but I am not sure how to achieve this.
Here is form:

```
  <g:form controller="customer" action="saveCustomer" class="customer-form">

                        <form>
                            <div class = "row">
                                <div class = "col-md-5 mx-auto" style = "margin:0px;padding:0px;">

                                    <h5 style="font-weight: bold;margin-left:15px;";>Please enter customer information:</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class = "row">
                                <div class = "col-md-5 mx-auto">


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input  type="text" required  class="form-control name" id="name" placeholder="Enter first and last name" name="name">
                            </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class = "row">
                                <div class="col-md-5 mx-auto">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="code">Code</label>
                                <input type="text" required  class="form-control" id="code" placeholder="Enter code" name="code">
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
</form>
</g:form>
```

And here is my domain class:

```
class Customer {
    String code
    String name

    static constraints = {
        code unique: true
        name nullable: false

    }
}
```

Any idea how can I achieve this? Many thanks.

Comment: I don't see any problems with your code. The "save" controller action should respond with validation error about "unique constraint"

Comment: I am new to grails. If you could provide me with an example would be really helpful.

Comment: show relevant code of your controller